# Major IP Address Blocks to Country Mappings

Tags: geolocation, ip

- Is there a standard of Major IP Address Blocks to Country mappings *(only interested in knowing where a user is at the Country level)*?
- If there isn't a standard, then how often do they change and is paying for a database of IP Addresses to Regions recommended (simple application)?
- If there is a standard, is there any documentation addressing this? Links? Resources?

Comment: used to be, not anymore. now that the IPv4 space is essentially exhausted, blocks are being traded around like crazy, and any original "this block is country X's" no longer applies, because those blocks are now fragmented beyond belief.